# Figuring out how to change linux commands to powershell in a CloudFormation template for Dynatrace tag

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cloudformation, dynatrace

I've been scratching my head for the better part of a day trying to figure out how to take this:

```
sudo su - 
cd /opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/tools
./oneagentctl --set-host-property=o11y-ci=my-new-tag-01 --restart-service
```

Into its powershell equivalent. I'm working on a CloudFormation template that deploys an EC2 and we want to ensure that any newly created or migrated EC2 instances will properly route the out of the box incidents to our servicenow. Which is where the my-new-tag-01 comes in (changed name for privacy reasons but the name of our tag will be formatted just like that).

In our template under Metadata we have already two other lines of powershell that executes when the pattern is deployed:

```
    08_setup_dynatrace-oneagent:
      commands:
        01download_oneagent:
          command: !Sub 'powershell.exe -Command Read-S3Object -Bucket ${pDynaTraceOneAgentS3Bucket} -Key ${pDynaTraceClusterEnv}/windows/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-Install.exe -File C:\Dynatrace\Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-Install.exe'
        02install_oneagent:
          command: !Sub 'powershell.exe -Command C:\Dynatrace\Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-Install.exe --set-host-group=${pOperatingCompany}-${pApp}-${pTier}'
```

I've been trying to have mine similar to those, and was thinking of putting me right under the second one, something like:

```
        03configure_oneagent_tag:
          command: !Sub 'powershell.exe -Command C:\"Program Files"\dynatrace\oneagent\agent\tools; .\oneagentctl --set-host-property=o11y-ci=aws-ent-appmod-01 --restart-service'
```

But the tag doesn't show up when I search for this EC2 in Dynatrace under the Properties and Tags section. Is there something I'm messing up on this script? Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried writing the script as:
command: !Sub 'powershell.exe -Command C:"Program Files"\dynatrace\oneagent\agent\tools; .\oneagentctl --set-host-property=o11y-ci=aws-ent-appmod-01 --restart-service'
And I've also tried:
command: !Sub 'powershell.exe -Command cd C:\”Program Files”\dynatrace\oneagent\agent\tools; .\oneagentctl --set-host-property=o11y-ci=aws-ent-appmod-01 --restart-service’

Comment: Have you checked the userdata logs?

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up, I was able to check the logs in my EC2 and that did just help me see what the template was not liking, was able to solve it, I appreciate your help!